# Arranging array in php

Tags: php

my problem is i can't arrange the array in the structure i want.
array1 and array2 are generated dynamically.  as you can see in the array 2 it has a subjectid which is the same in array1, that means, that element is under the subject cpe 305. all elements in the array 2 which has the id of 5 is under the the subject of cpe 305. same logic with cpe 304.

**array1:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [subjectid] => 5
        [subjectcode] => Cpe 305
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [subjectid] => 4
        [subjectcode] => Cpe 304
    )

)
```

**array2:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [subjectid] => 5
        [soid] => 1
        [socode] => A
        [sodesc] => Ability to apply knowledge of mathematics and science to solve engineering problems
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [subjectid] => 5
        [soid] => 3
        [socode] => C
        [sodesc] => Ability to design a system, component, or process to meet the desired needs within realistic constraints such as economic, environmental, social, political, ethical, health and safety, manufacturability, and sustainability, in accordance to standards
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [subjectid] => 5
        [soid] => 4
        [socode] => D
        [sodesc] => Ability to function on multidisciplinary teams
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [subjectid] => 5
        [soid] => 5
        [socode] => E
        [sodesc] => Ability to identify, formulate, and solve engineering problems
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [subjectid] => 5
        [soid] => 9
        [socode] => I
        [sodesc] => Recognition of the need for, and an ability to engage in life-long learning
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [subjectid] => 4
        [soid] => 10
        [socode] => J
        [sodesc] => Knowledge of contemporary issues
    )
```

)

**OUTPUT (my desired structure)**

```
Array(
 [subjectid] => 5
 [subjectcode] => Cpe 305
 [sodetails] => array(
                [0]=>Array ([soid]=>1
                            [socode]=>A)
                [1]=>Array([soid]=>3
                           [socode]=>C .....until the last
                 )
 [subjectid] => 4
 [subjectcode] => Cpe 305
 [sodetails] => array(
                [0]=>Array ([soid]=>10
                            [socode]=>J)
                                      .......until the last
                 )
```

**what i've tried**

this is the code that im testing. i only include few data here in my test code.

```
      $so = array();
      $exist = array();

         foreach ($this->subject as $key => $value) {
          foreach ($this->sodetails as $key2 => $value2) {
            if($value['subjectid'] === $value2['subjectid']){

              $exist = array(
                  "subjectid" => $value['subjectid'],
                  "details" =>array(
                    "soid" => $value2['soid']
                  )
              );
              array_push($so, $exist);
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried writing code? Show us your effort in solving this problem

Comment: Show us your tries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your output array is incorrect. An array cannot have more than one same indexes like "subjectid", "subjectcode". We need to have a different index. It will be wise to use subjectid as index for outer array.

First prepare your outer array as it is array1.

```
foreach($this->subject as $key => $val){
    $myArray[$val['subjectid']]['subjectid'] => $val['subjectid'];
    $myArray[$val['subjectid']]['subjectcode'] => $val['subjectcode'];
}
```

Now iterate your sodetails array.

```
foreach($this->sodetails as $key => $val){
    $temp['soid'] = $val['soid'];
    $temp['socode'] = $val['socode'];
    array_push($myArray[$val['subjectid']]['sodetails'], $temp);
}
```

There can be other ways too. But it is my style and I believe it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running the loop/iterations for `m x n` times, what you could do is first have the `subjectid` as the key for the `$arrray1` and let the natural PHP array key handling do the job.

```
$new_array1 = array();
foreach($arrray1 as $item){
 $new_array1[$item['subjectcode']] = $item;
}

foreach($array2 as $desc){
 if(array_key_exists($desc['subjectid'],$new_array1){
  $new_array1[$desc['subjectid']]['desc'][] = $desc;
 }
}
```

This way you only have to make `m + n` iterations.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass subjectid as key in your return array,

```
 $exist = array();
            foreach ($this->subject as $key => $value) {
              foreach ($this->sodetails as $key2 => $value2) {
                if($value['subjectid'] === $value2['subjectid']){
                    $exist[$value['subjectid']]['subjectid'] = $value['subjectid'];
                    $exist[$value['subjectid']]['subjectcode'] = $value['subjectcode'];
                    $exist[$value['subjectid']]['sodetails'] = array(array('soid'=>$value2['soid']),array('socode'=>$value2['socode']));
                }
              }
            }
```